# How to view the vhost associated with an apache process

Tags: linux, virtualhost, ubuntu-18.04, top

Using the "top" command (or a similar command) in Linux, is there anyway to show the vhost that an apache process is associated with in /var/www/html? I have 250 websites on a linux server, and I am trying to associate apache processes with the website that is being accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache mod_status for that. Please see [module manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) for information on how to enable and use it.

I've also found [this guide](https://www.tecmint.com/monitor-apache-web-server-load-and-page-statistics/) which also shows an example on what information you can get from it.

There is also 3rd party tool called [apachetop](https://github.com/igloonet/apache-top) if you would prefer getting info from the console. But it still relies on mod_status for this. But if you prefer to get that info from the console, that might be of use.